# Adding subtabs to XtraTabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, devexpress

In my WinForms project I use XtraTabControl with some tabs. I would like to have an additional row of tabs (subtabs) that would appear after clicking on given tab from top row. Is there an easy way to obtain it?

Comment: Can't you just add another TabControl to the TabPage of the selected tab?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [LayoutControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3406/Controls-and-Libraries/Form-Layout-Managers/Layout-Manager) with [Tabbed Groups](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/2170/Controls-and-Libraries/Form-Layout-Managers/Layout-Manager/Tabbed-Groups/Tabbed-Group). This way you can create layouts of any complexity with better performance (comparing to using multiple tab controls)